# How to "give users the ability to turn sharing off/on globally"

Tags: facebook, graph, action

I sent an application for review at Facebook and received the following response

> Status: Changes needed
>   Unfortunately, your article.read built-in submission does not meet the read requirements specified at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read. You must give users the ability to turn sharing off/on globally as well as remove an article that was shared within the app. In addition, read actions should only be generated when there is a strong indication that the user is actually reading the article. Please re-submit when these features have been added to your site. We appreciate your patience. Note: If you are creating an aggregation based on the object, you need to add 6-7 unique sample objects, and then create a corresponding sample action acting on each of these unique objects. (You can not just create 6-7 sample actions pointing to the same sample object). Submission Checklist: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/checklist
>   Please make changes below and resubmit for review.

But I don't know how to "give users the ability to turn sharing off/on globally".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve requirement of "On/Off publishing" for 'read article' action](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10206525/how-to-solve-requirement-of-on-off-publishing-for-read-article-action)

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it for my open graph action is to have a setting in a profile where they can toggle it off and on. If the toggle is off, I do an IF statement to not display the code that sends the Action. Then obviously I display that code if the toggle is set to on.

Without knowing more information on your system or all that, I can't really give more specifics on how to actually do it...

Comment: I want to post an action 'read' when the user loads the page.

Here's a screenshot of my action.

[Here's a screenshot of my action](http://i1168.photobucket.com/albums/r493/eduardo_Leal_/Capturar.png).

Comment: May you show me how to have a setting in a profile? That's my problem.

Comment: Ah, okay. Here is a screenshot of our backend with the toggle: [http://d.pr/qwER](http://d.pr/qwER) - Is that what you want to see?

Comment: No, I've done that.

I want to see where I keep the value of "sharing on/off" on app's facebook page.

Do I need to put a new custom property in action settings?